# Hold register details after error message to prevent re-entering of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I hold the half entered details that a user when attempting to create a user for my webpage?
If, for example, the user only fills out the 'USERNAME' field, I want the error to flag, redirecting them back to the register page, but I want the fields that they previously entered to remain filled.

Any ideas please? :(

**The Register Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Classic - Vintage Cinema Reviews</title>
      <link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <meta name="description" content="A unique, ground-breaking website for all things relating to classical cinema. The Classic revolutionises the way that we see classic cinema, and provides the movie goer with an opportunity to find all the reviews they need!">
      <meta name="author" content="Stefan Batterbee">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="page">
         <header> <?php
         session_start();
         if(isset($_SESSION['Logged_In']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else
{   
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'You are not logged in!<br>';
    echo '<a href="log_in.php">Click here to log in,</a><br>';
    echo 'or register below.';

}
?>


</header>
         <nav>
            <ul id="navigation">
               <li><a href="index.php">H O M E </a></li>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <li><a href="genres(list).php">F I L M&nbsp; R E V I E W S </a></li>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <li><a href="articles(list).php">A R T I C L E S</a></li>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <li><a href="about_us.php">A B O U T &nbsp;U S</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div id="breadcrumbs">
            &nbsp;<a class="link" href="index.php">Home</a> > Register
         </div>
         <div id="main">

         <centre>
         <?php

if( isset($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']) && count($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']) >0 ) {
     echo '<h3 style="color:#F00;">';
    foreach($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE'] as $msg) {
        echo $msg; 
    }
     echo '</h3><br>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']);
}
?>

<br>
<center><h1>Welcome to The Classic!</h1><br>
<h3>You can create an account below to become an exclusive member of our website.<br>
Just simply fill our your details below, and we will create your account!<br>
<p>If you already have an account, please go to the log in page.</p></h3></center><br><br>

</centre>

<div id="loginbox">
        <form method="post" action="regprocess.php">

    <h3>Username:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br>
    <h3>Password:</h3>
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
    <h3>Confirm Password:</h3>
    <input type="password" name="password2" /><br>
    <h3>First Name:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value=""/><br>
    <h3>Surname:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create your account!" /><br><br>
    Already a user? Log in <a class="link" href="register.php">HERE</a><br>

</form>
</div><br><br>


         </div>
         <footer>
            <p class="textleft">Created by Stefan Batterbee (2013)</p>
            <p class="textright">Click <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/the.classic.cinema.reviews">HERE</a> to access our Facebook page.</p>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**The Processing Script**

```
<?php
session_start();
include"config.php";

$error_message = array();
$error = false;
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname']; 

if($username == '') {
    $error_message[] = 'Please enter a username.';
    $error = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $error_message[] = 'Please enter a password.';
    $error = true;
}

if($password2 == '') {
    $error_message[] = 'Please enter a confirmation of your password.';
    $error = true;
}

if($fname == '') {
    $error_message[] = 'Please enter a first name.';
    $error = true;
}
if($lname == '') {
    $error_message[] = 'Please enter a last name.';
    $error = true;
}

if ($password != $password2)
 {
     $error_message[] = 'Your passwords did not match, please try again!';
    $error = true;
 }

if ($username && $password && $password2 && $fname && $lname != '' and $password == $password2) {
$insert = 'INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES("'.$username.'","'.$password.'","'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'")';
}




mysql_query($insert);
header('location: log_in.php');

if($error) {
    $_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE'] = $error_message;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: register.php");
    exit();
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In each value spot of each input, echo the posted value of that input.

```
<h3>Username:</h3>
<input type="text" name="username" 
    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']; ?>"/><br>
```

You check for `isset` first to see if it is in the post, and if it is, put it back into the input.

EDIT:

I forgot to add that you should do the processing on the same page, rather than doing a redirect.  That is what allows the post values to stick around so you can refill them into the form.  It will also make it no longer necessary to put your error message into a SESSION variable.

EDIT 2:

As was commented, you can also fill the post into the session.  The reason I don't do this is that, if a) the session were hijacked, or b) it's a public computer and someone else sits down at it, the person's registration data would show up again on the registration form.  If you choose to set the post values into the session, I strongly suggest that, at the end of printing out the form, you unset all the registration session values.  They will be lost on a page refresh, but it's more secure for the user.  It's a good idea to do this for your error message also, unless you want that error message to be stuck on the page forever.  E.g.:

```
//after the </form> tag
unset($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']);
unset($_SESSION['username']);
// ... and so forth for the rest
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked :| i'm not sure why?

Comment: See my edit.  You have to do the processing on the same page, or end up putting all the post values into the session along with the error message.  By the way, you have your `header()` call in the wrong spot.  You must call `header()` before printing out any html at all.

Comment: I deleted my comment on your deleted comment.  Now you can delete your comment on my deleted comment about your deleted comment and then I can delete this comment.  :)  @Fred-ii-

Comment: LMHO... deleted. Ok.. back to our regularly scheduled program ;-) @spsc_tech

Comment: You know, using 
`$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];`
then using 
`value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">` could work better if OP wants it in two seperate pages. That's what I use myself. It's another option. However, using [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) may be required.

Comment: Fred, that sounds like what I'm going for. Where is ob_start() required? Im not aware of the function sorry!

Comment: Never mind, you resolved it thank you. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: dont' redirect if you don't want to lose the user's input data. just popup a register prompt box

Answer (score 0):

As per [your request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125324/hold-register-details-after-error-message-to-prevent-re-entering-of-data#comment31789708_21125373):

Using [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) could work better if you're planning on using your code in two seperate pages.

You would first assign your session name to your POST name:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

then using it inside your input element:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
```

That's what I use myself. It's another option.

However, using [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) is usually required when using sessions, by placing it on top of `session_start();` yet required since you are using `header()`. Not using `ob_start();` will result in an `headers already sent` error message.

For example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

// ...
```

---

**Footnotes:** `session_start();` must reside inside all files using the same session(s).

---